# cast Or Convert

Tags: c#, casting

in the my code,district of demarcated ,is cast or convert??

```
static  List<int> b;
MemoryStream c = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter g=new BinaryFormatter();
g.Serialize(c,b);

byte[] ui= c.ToArray();
c.Position = 0;
List<int> hj = (List<int>)g.Deserialize(c);
```

Comment: What programming language ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: What is this, I don't even...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting by writing (List)g.Deserialize(c);

You can always check if you can cast or not by using "is" operator:

```
ClassA obj1 = new ClassA();
ClassB obj2 = new ClassB();

if(obj1 is ClassB) { 
//you can cast
}
```

In your code you can achieve that:

```
if(g.Deserialize(c) is List<int>) {
List<int> hj = (List<int>)(g.Deserialize(c));
}
```

Comment: there is way for check convert??

Answer (score 1):

using `(List<int>)****` you are performing a cast that will fail if the deserialized object can't be cast to the target type. Casting has not to do with `System.Convert`. In order to convert from a type to another System.Convert has to know how to do it ( and this is done for base types ), or your custom type has to implement `IConvertible`.